# I have installed "share this" to my blog and when the I click the facebook like button only a part of it shows up on screen. How do I fix this?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

I emailed support and they replied by saying to add this code to my css.

```
**span.st_fblike_hcount span div.fb-like span iframe#f249dba5d33c086.fb_ltr
{
height: 234px !important;
max-width: 634% !important;
}**
```

I am new to programming and do not know where exactly I should add this code. Can some one please instruct me on how to correct this problem.

My url [My Blog](http://cookwithjack.com/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you need to go into the plugin folder and modify the CSS file.  In the sharthis folder is a file called sharthis.css

Open the file in a text editor and add the following code that they gave you.

```
span.st_fblike_hcount span div.fb-like span iframe#f249dba5d33c086.fb_ltr
{
height: 234px !important;
max-width: 634% !important;
}
```

Save and refresh the page and it should work